# Finishing basement. Need advice for receiver/speaker setup

Tags: electrical, basement

I am finishing my basement and have been looking for a solution that'll allow me
to do the following:

1. Play sound from my TV to a number of ceiling speakers placed throughout the basement
2. Play music from a USB stick to the ceiling speakers
3. Play music from a device (like an iPod/iPhone/Android device) to the ceiling speakers

Those are the basic requirements.

I am not an audiophile. I just need a decent receiver and some decent ceiling speakers. I am not
looking to spend 1000s of dollars on this either. I do want the sound to be "rich" and not tinny.

Here's the receiver I am considering to buy: Denon-AVR-X2200W

And here is the type of ceiling speaker I am considering: Infinity CS60R

I plan to buy 6 in total.

Here's a drawing of the layout of the basement.

[image: basement layout]

Nice-to-have:

Ideally, it would be awesome if the receiver would allow me to create 2 "sound zones" so that
I can send the same sound to both zones or send one sound to one zone and another sound source
to another zone and set the volume level of each zone individually. For example, Zone 1 could be
the ceiling speakers (4) which are not directly above the sitting area where I watch TV. And Zone 2
could be the ceiling speakers which are above the sitting/TV area (2). In that case, I would love to
be able to send the TV sound at one volume level to Zone 2, and music from a USB stick would be
played to Zone 1 at another volume level. Is this possible?

Questions:

1. What do I need to buy besides the receiver and the speakers? Obviously I need to buy cables
   so that the general contractor can run the cables from the receiver to wherever they need to
   go. But which cables should I buy? And is there anything else I need to buy besides cables?
2. How should the speakers be placed to get the best "sound experience". I have indicated in
   the drawing how I intend to have the ceiling speakers placed, but I'm not sure if the placement
   is "correct" or optimal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your receiver does have a USB port, assuming that will accept a memory stick but you should verify its purpose and functionality. For the best experience with Apple devices look for built in Airplay or CarPlay in the receiver specs, I don't see it on the Denon.

Comment: This seems off topic here, but I'm not sure if a decision has ever been made either way about home sound systems.

Comment: @Tester101 it's also almost a shopping question, and the part that is not (speaker placement) can only be answered in very general terms, certainly no more specific than his diagram is now, as room acoustics can't truly be judged from a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The Denon receiver you linked to should do what you want -- it can output to 7 speakers plus a subwoofer, and it can play from a different source simultaneously through two of its speakers (the surround back R & L). However, it's meant as a "home theater receiver" and not really a "multiroom audio receiver", so it may take some finicking with the settings to get everything to sound right. You might consider consulting a forum more suited for home audio enthusiasts for recommendations on specific receivers. At a minimum, I'd strongly suggest downloading the receiver's manual and reading through it to see if it has the options you need.

For your specific questions:

1. You need speaker wire. There are countless varieties of this, so just pick an option with a thick enough gauge (the longer the cable run, [the thicker a gauge you'll want](http://www.crutchfield.com/S-rvQPfoqdwOG/learn/learningcenter/home/speakers_wire.html)) and check that it's rated for in-wall use. Your speakers won't need any special type of connection (just strip the ends of each lead and plug the exposed copper into the jacks).
2. Ceiling speakers are, in my opinion, never going to give the best sound experience (there's a reason the standard home theater setup is to put speakers level with the listeners' ears). Assuming you're going to be putting out the same mono signal through each speaker, I don't think the particular layout of the speakers will make a huge difference. If you're interested in controlling each speaker's volume (or perhaps expanding your setup in the future), a multiroom receiver like [this one I picked randomly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WFIISSG) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question will last since the answer requires an opinion as the answer.

So I will give you my thoughts. The only real thing to be considered is for the sound to make sense to the listeners. I have been in construction, video and sound, plus deejaying for 30 years. The area is so small that any decent speaker or amp/receiver combination should work well. Just know what you need. Those speakers that are grouped in 2's need to be left and right so when under that area, it is in stereo. If not all 6 need to be ran as mono, or you will most likely miss a lot of sound by not being in a stereo hearing range. When a listener is not stationed then stereo sound should not be considered. Now if the pairs are done in left and right and you are creating seating/standing areas, then of course stereo sounds richer and go with that. Most venues are done in mono unless seated. You should not go with any type of dolby or surround sound as the layout would confuse the listener from bizarre distribution of tracks. Anyhow good luck. Cheers